# How do I merge update a document using mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a model schema in moongose:

```
const usersSchema = new Schema({
  users: [
    {
      username: { type: String, required: true },
      actions: [
        {
          action: { type: String },
          description: { type: String, required: true }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
});
```

Also i have one document in my mongodb:

```
{ user: 'John', action: [{ action: 'Like', description: 'Like post' },{ action: 'Share', description: 'Share post' }] }
```

Now with the PATCH request i get an updated object that i want to merge with the old document

```
{
  users: [
    {
      user: 'John',
      action: [{ action: 'Delete', description: 'Delete Post' }]
    },
    {
      user: 'Robert',
      action: [{ action: 'Share', description: 'Share post' }]
    }
  ]
};
```

I can pull the old doc from database and with spread operator or `Object.assign()` merge the object,But this is problematic because over time the document will increase and the pull action will take longer.

This is the final result i try to get.

```
{
  users: [
    {
      user: 'John',
      action: [
        { action: 'Like', description: 'Like post' },
        { action: 'Share', description: 'Share post' },
        { action: 'Delete', description: 'Delete Post' }
      ]
    },
    {
      user: 'Robert',
      action: [{ action: 'Share', description: 'Share post' }]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an aggregation pipeline to process your request body and transform the `users` collection to your expected result. Finally do a `$merge` to update to your collection.

Here are the steps:

1. `$addFields` to add the patch request as a field `patchRequest` for easier processing
2. `$project` the fields condtionally. `$concatArrays` if `user` is the same as `patchRequest.users.user`, otherwise simply use `patchRequest.users.action` as `action`
3. finally merge on `user`, which I believe is the key for your case. Replace the document if matched and insert if not matched.

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/C6oM_QkvmUD) for your reference.